# How to properly copy a pandas dataframe into another variable?

Tags: python, pandas

Someone was reviewing my code and told me to use the `.copy()` function when copying a pandas dataframe into another variable. My code was like this:

`data1 = pd.DataFrame()`

`data1[['Country/Region','Province/State','Lat','Long']]=confirmed[['Country/Region','Province/State','Lat','Long']]`

I copied the dataframe into another dataframe like this:

`data2 = data1` and was working alright. Alright means, `data1` is not being changed when I work on the `data2`. So, I am guessing it is ok. I am using Jupyter Notebook.

Should I stick to using it in the future or use `.copy()`?

Comment: What is the code meant to do here? Are you using `data2` as an intermediate variable to copy the DF to `data2` ? All you need is `data2 = confirmed[['Country/Region','Province/State','Lat','Long']].copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

toking, normally if you say `data2=data1` it passes to data2 the reference (a pointer) to data1. Thus when you make changes to data2 you really making them on data1. In your case, however, you already allocated memory to your data2, thus `data1[['Country/Region','Province/State','Lat','Long']]=confirmed[['Country/Region','Province/State','Lat','Long']]` code copies the content to the allocated memory. But it is generally a good practice to use .copy(deep=True) if you want to avoid confusion. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `=` is used to assign one variable to another. If you use just `=` you may have some unexpected values, like the simple example below:

```
a = [1,2,3]

b = a

b.append([5,6,7])

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, [5, 6, 7]]
```

If you are appending values to `b`, why it's doing the same with `a`? It's because you assigned them with an equal sign `=`. Anything you do with `a` will be also done in `b` and vice-versa.

That's why you should use `.copy()` instead of `=`. The logic is valid for `DataFrame` and any other object in python.